# PlatformRef.bootstrapModule(...) throws an error that says "No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided."

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

I am attempting to create an `NgModuleRef<AppModule>` in order to render some of my components into non-html formats.

I was able to create a `PlatformRef` object, however when I am calling `bootstrapModule(AppModule)` on this object I get an error:

> "Error: No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided. Can't read the url "app.component.html""

Probably, I should be adding a DI registration of `ResourceLoader` in a place different from `extraProviders`, but I don't know where exactly...

## Code:

```
import { ResourceLoader } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Compiler, CompilerFactory, Injectable, StaticProvider, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { platformDynamicServer } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

export function createCompiler(compilerFactory: CompilerFactory) {
  return compilerFactory.createCompiler();
}

async function generate<M>(moduleType: Type<M>) {
  try {
    const extraProviders: StaticProvider[] = [
      { provide: ResourceLoader, useClass: ResourceLoaderImpl, deps: [] },
      { provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory] },
    ];
    const platformRef = platformDynamicServer(extraProviders);
    const moduleRef = await platformRef.bootstrapModule(moduleType);   // <<< BREAKS HERE

    const appComponent = moduleRef.injector.get(AppComponent);

    console.info(appComponent.title.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.toString());
  }
}

generate(AppModule)
  .then(message => console.info({ message }))
  .catch(error => console.error({ error }));
```

The `ResourceLoaderImpl` class code is copied to the letter from `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic` (`src\resource_loader\resource_loader_impl.ts`):

```
@Injectable()
export class ResourceLoaderImpl extends ResourceLoader {
  get(url: string): Promise<string> {
    let resolve: (result: any) => void;
    let reject: (error: any) => void;
    const promise = new Promise<string>((res, rej) => {
      resolve = res;
      reject = rej;
    });
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'text';

    xhr.onload = function() {
      // responseText is the old-school way of retrieving response (supported by IE8 & 9)
      // response/responseType properties were introduced in ResourceLoader Level2 spec (supported
      // by IE10)
      const response = xhr.response || xhr.responseText;

      // normalize IE9 bug (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1450)
      let status = xhr.status === 1223 ? 204 : xhr.status;

      // fix status code when it is 0 (0 status is undocumented).
      // Occurs when accessing file resources or on Android 4.1 stock browser
      // while retrieving files from application cache.
      if (status === 0) {
        status = response ? 200 : 0;
      }

      if (200 <= status && status <= 300) {
        resolve(response);
      } else {
        reject(`Failed to load ${url}`);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() { reject(`Failed to load ${url}`); };

    xhr.send();
    return promise;
  }
}
```

Comment: wanna try using `require`... instead of `templateUrl: './my.component.html'` to `template: require('./my.component.html')`

Comment: @JSON, no, I want to keep my target module's code intact.

Comment: Can you try `platformRef.bootstrapModule(moduleType, { providers: [{provide: ResourceLoader, useClass: ResourceLoaderImpl, deps: []}]});`?

Comment: Or something like https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8fa099158e54f96dd60f4612862e3400a6f0d9bd/packages/platform-webworker-dynamic/src/platform-webworker-dynamic.ts#L22-L25

Comment: @yurzui the attempt with `bootstrapModule(moduleType, compilerOptions)` resulted in `ResourceLoader` being picked up. Now I need to make the implementation class work as necessary *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResourceLoader` is a part of CompilerOptions therefore you should provide them.

It could be done eiher via [platformRef.bootstrapModule](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8fa099158e54f96dd60f4612862e3400a6f0d9bd/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L259) as second `CompilerOptions` parameter:

```
platformRef.bootstrapModule(moduleType, { 
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ResourceLoader, 
      useClass: ResourceLoaderImpl, deps: []
    }
  ]
});
```

or you can try to provide `COMPILER_OPTIONS` token as multi provider(here's [an example](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8fa099158e54f96dd60f4612862e3400a6f0d9bd/packages/platform-webworker-dynamic/src/platform-webworker-dynamic.ts#L22-L25) from source code):

```
const extraProviders: StaticProvider[] = [
  {
    provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS,
    useValue: {providers: [{provide: ResourceLoader, useClass: ResourceLoaderImpl, deps: []}]},
    multi: true
  },
  { provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory] },
];
```